# Implementation of algorithm to determine next basket recommendation?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, matrix-decomposition, tensor

I hope I am asking in right forum, and forgive me, if I am wrong.

I am trying to implement an algorithm based on an open paper `Factorizing Personalized Markov Chains for Next-Basket Recommendation` by `Steffen Rendle`.

In this paper, they combine the morkov chain and matrix factorisation to improve accuracy of next basket recommendation.

According to this paper, there is two steps, (1) finding out transition matrix for each user (2) Factorisation using S-BPR.

I already completed the creation of transition matrix for each user and obtained the transition cube (3d array). This is till `Section 4.1` in the paper.

From `Section 4.2`, the factorisation part starts and I am totally lost because I am not able to understand the notations used in the equations.

Most importantly, the paper provides an algorithm with S has input and I don't understand how to transform the transition matrix (or cube) to S.

Can somebody explain what is happening from `Section 4.2` and how to transform my each user transition matrix to S (for using in provided algorithm)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I figured it out.

For others.

The algorithm gives a solution using the decomposition matrix of transition cube for memory management. Hence, just implementing the algorithm with (user_id, time (or sequence #), item_id) as input will give a solution

Answer (score 1):

Since this appeared in my google search, here are two links to implementations of this paper on GitHub. The first repo has a better API than the second. I have not verified the correctness of these implementations though.

https://github.com/khesui/FPMC

https://github.com/flaviovdf/fpmc